# Variables undeclared with List<MyCustomMetadata__mdt>

Tags: apex, list, metadata, sobject, custom

When I changed from the code that's commented out to the current code, the fields from the custom metadata records threw "Variable does not exist" errors. Suggestions on how to correct this?

Relevant Code Snippet

```
        public void bindServiceTypesAndCapabilities(){
    // List<ServiceOffered__c> servicesList = [Select ID, Services__c, Capabilities__c, Sub_Capabilities__c From ServiceOffered__c];
    List<VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt> servicesList = [SELECT ID, Services__c, Capabilities__c, Sub_Capabilities__c FROM VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt];
    // Above does not like List "Unexpected token'List'" when I try to use List. Removed [] and added List<>
    lstServiceTypes = new List<Selectoption>();                     //Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups(List<String> sobjects)
    Set<String> stService = new Set<String>();
    //for ( ServiceOffered__c svcItem : servicesList ) {
    for ( VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt[] svcItem : servicesList ) {
        if ( !stService.contains(svcItem.Services__c)) {            // adding VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt.Services__c "Can't assign static to sObject fields" 
            lstServiceTypes.add(new selectoption(svcItem.Services__c, svcItem.Services__c));
            stService.add(svcItem.Services__c);
        }
    }
```

Variable does not exist: Services__c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the crux:

```
//for ( ServiceOffered__c svcItem : servicesList ) {
for ( VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt[] svcItem : servicesList ) {
```

Notice how you went from a single record (`ServiceOffered__c`) to a collection (`VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt[]`). Change the loop variable type to `VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt`. Currently your loop variable is of the type `List<...>`, and that type does not have any attribute by the name of `Services__c`.

Comment: WhooHoo! That did it.

Comment: I have to wait another 17 seconds to accept your answer as the best. Weird rules here :-)

Comment: @Wade The 15 minute window where you can't accept an answer makes sense in lots of scenarios. Read more about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer). The general SE principle is there might be many good answers, and it should take a minimum amount of time to verify correctness for nontrivial solutions. Often questions and answers on this exchange in particular don't fit that pattern, because there's one obvious thing to fix. But patience to see if better answers roll in is often advised when there is more substance to the question.

Answer (score 1):

`servicesList` variable is type of `List` class `List<VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt> servicesList`. So to iterate this collection, change:

```
for ( VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt[] svcItem : servicesList )
```

to

```
for ( VRM_Vendor_Services__mdt svcItem : servicesList )
```